# generator-angular-fullstack cannot add angular-chart.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js, angular-fullstack, angular-chart

I have recently started to use angular, more specifically the generator angular-fullstack (https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack).

I try to use the angular-chart-js (https://github.com/jtblin/angular-chart.js) library for displaying graph in my app but unsuccefully. I always get an error when I add chart.js in the "app" module dependency.

### What I have done :

Installing angular-chart.js with the command "npm install --save angular-chart.js" (in my app root folder), I have checked the dependency in the "package.json" file.

Modify index.html and _index.html

```
<head>
    <script src="../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>
    <script src="../node_modules/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
</head>
```

app.js

```
angular.module('myApp', ['chart.js']);
```

This config gives me the error

> Module 'chart.js' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

### After I have tried a different configuration

Move the line from index.html and _index.html to main.html

main.html

```
<script src="../../../node_modules/chart.js/dist/Chart.js"></script>
<script src="../../../node_modules/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.js"></script>
```

Import the library in a different way, and disable the strict mode app.js.

app.js

```
import chartJs from 'chart.js';
angular.module('myApp', [chartJs]);

angular.element(document)
  .ready(() => {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'], {
      strictDi: false
    });
  });
```

and with this setup I get this error

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module function (context, config) due to:
>   Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: context

If you need more informations, just tell me.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the bug !!

Here is my changes

app.js

```
import chartJs from 'angular-chart.js';
angular.module('myApp', [chartJs]);

angular.element(document)
  .ready(() => {
    angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'], {
      strictDi: true
    });
  });
```

The library name was wrong, and I can enable again the "strict mode".